# Error: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory

Tags: angularjs, babeljs, apollo-server

```
  {
  "name": "package.js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "babel-watch server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "expo": "^26.0.0",
    "react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-26.0.0.tar.gz"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-watch": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "depencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^1.3.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "graphql": "^0.13.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^2.20.2"
  }
}
```

Error that displays after executing npm run dev. Error log posted below. I am fairly new to GraphQL, Apollo, and Angular.

```
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error backend@1.0.0 dev: `babel-watch server.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the backend@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

If I'm missing any other files, feel free to ask in the comments.

Server.Js

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { graphqlExpress } from 'apollo-server-express';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World'));

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Express server running on port 4000'));
```

Comment: explain a bit what you want to achieve with the code

Comment: @lbo I'm trying to display "hello world' on localhost:4000 after executing the command npm run dev

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's missing the package `babel-preset-env`, just install it with `npm install babel-preset-env`.

If that does not fix it, might be because you have another `npm` instance in a different command line. Check if there is any other npm running in the same port. 
Also remove `node_modules` and clean cache `npm cache clean` and then re-install your node modules(`npm install`).